# PHP for loop - display data in table

Tags: php, html, mysql

i can't understand why my code is not working; it is only displaying 1 result, whereas there are multiple entries in table..

```
<?php  

    $search = $_POST['search'];
    print ($search);
    $query  = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE county= 'sussex'";
    $result = mysql_query($query,$conn);
    $counter = 0;
    $z=0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $id[$counter] = $row['roll_number'];
    $counter = $counter + 1;
    }
?>
<table border="1" id="table1" >
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Operator Id</th>

<?
    if($counter>0)
    {
        for($z=0;$z<$counter;$z++)
        {
?> 
            <tr>
            <?
                if($z<$counter)
                {
            ?>
                <td >
                    <?php echo $id[$z]?>                            
                </td> 
            <?
                }
                $z = $z + 1;
            ?>   
            </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM student WHERE county= 'sussex'` - There is your problem trying to finding a student in Sussex!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to close the FOR loop and its enclosing IF, I've done it below:

```
<?
if($counter>0)
{
    for($z=0;$z<$counter;$z++)
    {
?> 
        <tr>
            <?
                if($z<$counter)
                {
            ?>
                <td >
                    <?php echo $id[$z]?>                            
                </td> 
            <?
                }
                //$z = $z + 1;  <!-- REMOVE or comment out this line -->
            ?>   
            </tr>
     <? }
     }  ?> <!-- HERE we close the for loop and the IF -->
</table>
```

**UPDATE**: noted, thanks to VinceBurn, that $z was incremented twice

Comment: And Also you are incrementing $z at 2 different place.

Comment: its still not working...its display 1 entry and this line on html page.  0)
{
    for($z=0;$z<$counter;$z++)