# Display all the data from the database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display all the data from my database
My database is the below...
[image]

and I achieved to do that in my site...
[image]

But how I can load each of these data in each of this tables.
My code is the below...

```
<?php


include_once 'header.php';
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "smogi")
?>

<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<?php
$result = queryMysql("SELECT * FROM doctor WHERE username='$username'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result))
{
?>
<!-- Koumpi pou se metaferei sti selida gia tin dimiourgia neas anakoinwseis -->
<form action="new_announcement.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Create New Announcement">
</form>
<?php
}
else
{
    $query  = "SELECT author,category,subject,content FROM announcements";
    $announcements= mysql_query($query,$connection);
    $counter = 0;
    $z=0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($announcements)){
    $counter = $counter + 1;
?>

<table border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td><b>Author</b></td>
    <td><b>Category</b></td>        
    <td><b>Subject</b></td>
    <td><b>Content</b></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<?php
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I searched through the stackoverflow and I found some solution that could help me.
I used this [question from the stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542968/php-for-loop-display-data-in-table) to solve the problem with the tables but now how can i display the data into each table

Comment: You are looping your entire table, only loop the rows, also take some time to learn PDO, `mysql_()` is now deprecated

Comment: @Mr.Alien thank you for your comment, can you please change my code into an answer in order to understand which part of the code should i change, also thank you for the advice of the PDO I will take a look at it

Comment: `$row['col_name']` is what you need to use..

Comment: `$counter + 1` can be written as `$counter ++;`

Comment: I should place that `$row['col_name']` inside the `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($announcements))` , something like that `while($row['col_name'] = mysql_fetch_assoc($announcements))` ? Thank you again for ur time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<?php


include_once 'header.php';
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "smogi")
?>

<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<?php
$result = queryMysql("SELECT * FROM doctor WHERE username='$username'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result)):
?>
<!-- Koumpi pou se metaferei sti selida gia tin dimiourgia neas anakoinwseis -->
<form action="new_announcement.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Create New Announcement">
</form>
<?php else: ?>

<table border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td><b>Author</b></td>
    <td><b>Category</b></td>        
    <td><b>Subject</b></td>
    <td><b>Content</b></td>
  </tr>
<?php 
    $query  = "SELECT author,category,subject,content FROM announcements";
    $announcements= mysql_query($query,$connection);
    $counter = 0;
    $z=0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($announcements)){
    $counter = $counter + 1;
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['author']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['category']?></td>        
    <td><?php echo $row['subject']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['content']?></td>
  </tr>
<?php
    }
endif;
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @niklakis try again sir

Comment: Works fine . Can you keep the <b> tags only for the author,category,subject and content , I dont want the data from the database to be bolded